# Basic text replacement in Informatica

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I have data in informatica which I would like to do a textual search/replace.

I have a column in the source where records are in "12M" format and I want to replace that "M" and replace it with "1000000".

For example, "12M" would be come a numeric "12000000"

Answer (score 1):

```
IIF(
  SUBSTR(Column3,-1,1)='M',
  TO_DECIMAL(SUBSTR(Column3,1,(LENGTH(Column3)-1)))*1000000,
  TO_DECIMAL(Column3)
)
```

this is the correct way to find the desire results